# Delete bytea data from Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, binaryfiles, openerp-7

I'm using Openerp 7.0 and there are so many file that has been uploaded to that database
I want to delete every file that has been uploaded.
The Openerp is storing the data in a table called ir_attachment and a column db_datas that has type bytea.

So how do i delete every value from db_datas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL delete all content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223820/postgresql-delete-all-content)

Comment: Why don't you simply set the column to `null`?

Answer (score 1):

I actually need to vacuum after i set everything to null

update ir_attachment set db_datas = NULL;

VACUUM (VERBOSE, FULL) ir_attachment;

Comment: Does above command affect other rows and fields in that table?